# What is the difference between calls to `imread`in openCV?

Tags: c++, c, opencv

what is the difference between this calls to `imread`in openCV?On my local machine both of them work.

```
1) cv::imread(filename.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
2) cv::imread(filename,         CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

In the first  case we convert a std::string to C style string. 
In the second case we just pass a std::string to it.
Are this calls equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calls have the same effect. [`cv::imread`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) takes a `const std::string&` as first argument, so the first version would result in the creation of a temporary `std::string` object, constructed from the `const char*` returned by `filename.c_str()`.